Change colour of combo box based on content with only CSS
Is it possible to change the colour of a combo box based on it's content using CSS only? See image below, I want to change this to a specific colour if it has the word YES inside it using only CSS?

The reason I can only use CSS is because the vendor of this web based system only allows for stylesheet changes/customisations via the frontend.
I have managed to at least change the entire combo box colour regardless of content as a last resort option using the following CSS, any help would be much appreciated:

#ctl00_ctl00_contentPlaceHolderRoot_TaskSelectorsPlaceHolder_ctl00_autoCompleteLoc_comboBox{
background-color: yellow;
}



"Combo box" is a really ambiguous term. Please provide us with a proper [mre] of what you're actually dealing with there, and not just a screenshot.

it's not my code, how can I provide an MRE without copy and pasting the vendors HTML code which I don't want to do. Looks like what I want to do is not possible with just CSS anyway as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text
